# DJI drone not connecting (sdkManagerProductDidChange delegate method not called)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, dji-sdk

I can't seem to get my own app to connect to a particular drone. I have downloaded the bridger app and am using it to debug. I copied the "DJIBaseViewController" from the sample app and have made my own view controller a delegate of it. After adding alot of breakpoints to the code I have found that the major difference between my app and the sample app is that the delegate method "sdkManagerProductDidChange."

```
//  DJIBaseViewController.swift


import UIKit
import DJISDK

protocol DJIProductObjectProtocol {
    func fetchAircraft() -> DJIAircraft?
    func fetchCamera() -> DJICamera?
    func fetchGimbal() -> DJIGimbal?
    func fetchFlightController() -> DJIFlightController?
    func fetchRemoteController() -> DJIRemoteController?
    func fetchBattery() -> DJIBattery?
    func fetchAirLink() -> DJIAirLink?
    func fetchHandheldController() -> DJIHandheldController?
}

class ConnectedProductManager: DJIProductObjectProtocol {
    static let sharedInstance = ConnectedProductManager()

    var connectedProduct:DJIBaseProduct? = nil

    func fetchAircraft() -> DJIAircraft? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func fetchCamera() -> DJICamera? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).camera
        }
        else if (self.connectedProduct is DJIHandheld) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIHandheld).camera
        }

        return nil
    }

    func fetchGimbal() -> DJIGimbal? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).gimbal
        }
        else if (self.connectedProduct is DJIHandheld) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIHandheld).gimbal
        }

        return nil
    }

    func fetchFlightController() -> DJIFlightController? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).flightController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func fetchRemoteController() -> DJIRemoteController? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).remoteController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func fetchBattery() -> DJIBattery? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).battery
        }
        else if (self.connectedProduct is DJIHandheld) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIHandheld).battery
        }

        return nil
    }

    func fetchAirLink() -> DJIAirLink? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIAircraft) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIAircraft).airLink
        }
        else if (self.connectedProduct is DJIHandheld) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIHandheld).airLink
        }

        return nil
    }

    func fetchHandheldController() -> DJIHandheldController? {
        if (self.connectedProduct == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        if (self.connectedProduct is DJIHandheld) {
            return (self.connectedProduct as! DJIHandheld).handheldController
        }
        return nil
    }

    func setDelegate(delegate:DJIBaseProductDelegate?) {
        self.connectedProduct?.delegate = delegate
    }

}

class DJIBaseViewController: UIViewController, DJIBaseProductDelegate, DJIProductObjectProtocol {

    //var connectedProduct:DJIBaseProduct?=nil
    var moduleTitle:String?=nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (moduleTitle != nil) {
            self.title = moduleTitle
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct != nil) {
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.setDelegate(self)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(
        animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if (ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct != nil &&
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct?.delegate === self) {
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.setDelegate(nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func product(product: DJIBaseProduct, connectivityChanged isConnected: Bool) {
        if isConnected {
            NSLog("\(product.model) connected. ")
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct = product
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.setDelegate(self)

        }
        else {
            NSLog("Product disconnected. ")
            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct = nil
        }
    }

    func componentWithKey(withKey key: String, changedFrom oldComponent: DJIBaseComponent?, to newComponent: DJIBaseComponent?) {
        //     (newComponent as? DJICamera)?.delegate = self
        if ((newComponent is DJICamera) == true && (self is DJICameraDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJICamera).delegate = self as? DJICameraDelegate

        }
        if ((newComponent is DJICamera) == true && (self is DJIPlaybackDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJICamera).playbackManager?.delegate = self as? DJIPlaybackDelegate
        }

        if ((newComponent is DJIFlightController) == true && (self is DJIFlightControllerDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJIFlightController).delegate = self as? DJIFlightControllerDelegate
        }

        if ((newComponent is DJIBattery) == true && (self is DJIBatteryDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJIBattery).delegate = self as? DJIBatteryDelegate
        }

        if ((newComponent is DJIGimbal) == true && (self is DJIGimbalDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJIGimbal).delegate = self as? DJIGimbalDelegate
        }

        if ((newComponent is DJIRemoteController) == true && (self is DJIRemoteControllerDelegate) == true) {
            (newComponent as! DJIRemoteController).delegate = self as? DJIRemoteControllerDelegate
        }

    }


    func showAlertResult(info:String) {
        // create the alert
        var message:String? = info

        if info.hasSuffix(":nil") {
            message = info.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(":nil", withString: " success")
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: "\(message ?? "")", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func fetchAircraft() -> DJIAircraft?{
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchAircraft()
    }

    func fetchCamera() -> DJICamera? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchCamera()
    }

    func fetchGimbal() -> DJIGimbal? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchGimbal()
    }

    func fetchFlightController() -> DJIFlightController? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchFlightController()
    }

    func fetchRemoteController() -> DJIRemoteController? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchRemoteController()
    }

    func fetchBattery() -> DJIBattery? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchBattery()
    }
    func fetchAirLink() -> DJIAirLink? {
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchAirLink()
    }
    func fetchHandheldController() -> DJIHandheldController?{
        return ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.fetchHandheldController()
    }
}
```

The first view that loads after the splashscreen loads is.

```
//  MenuViewController.swift
import UIKit
import DJISDK

let enterDebugMode=true

class MenuViewController: DJIBaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var aircraft: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productID: UILabel!
              // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    @IBOutlet weak var appConectivity: UILabel!


        var connectedProduct:DJIBaseProduct?=nil
        var componentDictionary = Dictionary<String, Array<DJIBaseComponent>>()

        let APP_KEY = "*******"//Please enter App Key Here
        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()
            let air = self.fetchAircraft()

            if air == nil{
                aircraft.text?="no aircraft connected"
            }
            print(air?.model)
            initUI();

            guard !APP_KEY.isEmpty else {
                showAlert("Please enter your app key.")
                return
            }
            DJISDKManager.registerApp(APP_KEY, withDelegate: self)


            if DJISDKManager.product() == nil{
                productID.text?="Drone Not Connected"
            }
            else{
                productID.text? = "Drone Connected"
            }
        }

        func initUI() {
            self.title = "DJI iOS SDK Sample"
            //sdkVersionLabel.text = "DJI SDK Version: \(DJISDKManager.getSDKVersion())"
            //openComponents.isEnabled = false;
            //bluetoothConnectorButton.isEnabled = true;
            //productModel.isHidden = true
            //productFirmwarePackageVersion.isHidden = true
            //debugModeLabel.isHidden = !enterDebugMode
        }
    func showAlert(msg: String?) {
        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: msg, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
extension MenuViewController: DJISDKManagerDelegate{

        func sdkManagerDidRegisterAppWithError(error: NSError?) {

            guard error == nil  else {
                self.showAlertResult("Error:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                appConectivity.text?="app isn't registering properly"
                return
            }

            //Debug("Registered!")

            if enterDebugMode {

                DJISDKManager.enterDebugModeWithDebugId("10.202.38.238")
                print("WTF")
            }else{
                //DJISDKManager.enterDebugModeWithDebugId("10.202.38.238")
                DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()
            }

        }

        func sdkManagerProductDidChange(From oldProduct: DJIBaseProduct?, To newProduct: DJIBaseProduct?) {

            print("entered changed product")
            if oldProduct==nil{
                print("old product is nill")
            }
            if newProduct==nil{
                print("new product is nill")
            }

            guard let newProduct = newProduct else
            {
                appConectivity.text? = "Status: No Product Connected"

                ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct = nil
                //logDebug("Product Disconnected")
                return
            }

            //Updates the product's model
            productID.text = "Model: \((newProduct.model)!)"
            productID.hidden = false

            if let oldProduct = oldProduct {
                print("Product changed from: \(oldProduct.model) to \((newProduct.model)!)")
            }
            //Updates the product's firmware version - COMING SOON

            //Updates the product's connection status
            //appConectivity.text = "Status: Product Connected"

            ConnectedProductManager.sharedInstance.connectedProduct = newProduct
            productID.text?="product connected"
            //openComponents.isEnabled = true;
            //openComponents.alpha = 1.0;
            //logDebug("Product Connected")

        }
    override func product(product: DJIBaseProduct, connectivityChanged isConnected: Bool) {

            if isConnected {
                print("Status: Product Connected")
                //appConectivity.text?="Drone Recognized"
            } else {
                print("Status: No Product Connected")
                //appConectivity.text="Atleast Its trying"
            }
        }


    }
```

The sdkManager is registering properly with the given app key and bundler identifier. I have also added "Supported external accessory protocols" to my info.plist file with three elements com.dji.video, com.dji.protocol, and com.dji.common.

Been stuck here for quite some time and it's been damn frustrating. Hope someone call help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue here is that the sample app has named its delegate

```
func sdkManagerProductDidChange(from oldProduct: DJIBaseProduct?, to newProduct: DJIBaseProduct?)
```

whereas for whatever reason in my sample app the DJISDK knows my delegates function as

```
func sdkManagerProductDidChangeFrom(oldProduct: DJIBaseProduct?, to newProduct: DJIBaseProduct?)
```

a bit annoying that that made such a big difference but that's what I get for copying code I guess. Hope this is helpful to someone else down the road...

Cheers

P.S. they may change it again the way I found it is when I typed func into my extension section Xcode spit out a list of functions I could use and the sdkManagerDidChange was one of them with different input variables.

edit: if anyone can explain why it worked on the sample app and not mine that would be sweet too.